# C++ qsort 2D array

Tags: c++

I am still getting `lldb` error, because i am probably accessing memory, that i shouldn't.
 It looks like i am doing something wrong when manipulating with parameters in `io_seg_sort`, because before calling `qsort`, it is still ok.

```
    #define IO_SEG_IMAX (IO_SEG - 1)

    static int io_seg_sort (const void * seg1, const void * seg2) {

            int * _seg1 = (int *)seg1;
            int * _seg2 = (int *)seg2;

            cout << _seg1[1] <<endl; // this gives some random values and not what i am expecting

            if (_seg1[1] > _seg2[1]) {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (_seg1[1] < _seg2[1]) {
                return -1;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }

        }


            int **temp = new int *[IO_SEG];

            for (int i = 0; i <= IO_SEG_IMAX; i++) {
                temp[i] = new int[2];
                memcpy(temp[i], inputs[i], sizeof(int) * 2);
            }


            qsort(temp, IO_SEG, sizeof(int *) , io_seg_sort);
```

**EDIT1**: the problem is i am getting some random values in `io_seg_sort` when calling `cout` instead of what i am expecting. `inputs[i]` is class member `int inputs[IO_SEG][2]`;

Comment: why not use the C++ level **`std::sort`** from `algorithm`?

Comment: What is the relation between IO_SEG and IO_SEG_IMAX?

Comment: @Moberg it means IO_SEG_INDEX_MAX

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you just added the define which clarifies it. I thought I was quick enough to remove my comment, guess not ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary reason your code prints garbage is that you have mismatched levels of indirection inside the comparison function. Your `temp` array that you pass to `qsort` consists of *pointers* to two-element arrays. That means that inside the comparison function you actually receive *pointers to pointers to `int`*. I.e. this is already incorrect

```
static int io_seg_sort (const void * seg1, const void * seg2) {

        int * _seg1 = (int *)seg1;
        int * _seg2 = (int *)seg2;

        cout << _seg1[1] <<endl;
```

You have to do something like

```
static int io_seg_sort (const void * seg1, const void * seg2) {

        const int * _seg1 = *(const int *const *) seg1;
        const int * _seg2 = *(const int *const *) seg2;
```

to get access to your arrays through `_seg1` and `_seg2` as you do it in the body of `io_seg_sort` (I also added some `const` qualifiers, although they are not required for the code to work.)

Answer (score 3):

You're putting `IO_SEG_MAX + 1` items into an array that's `IO_SEG` long.

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= IO_SEG_IMAX; i++) {
        temp[i] = new int[2];
        memcpy(temp[i], inputs[i], sizeof(int) * 2);
    }
```

That should be:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < IO_SEG; i++) {
        temp[i] = new int[2];
        memcpy(temp[i], inputs[i], sizeof(int) * 2);
    }
```

But if you really intend to do this in C++, you should look into `std::vector` and `std::sort`.

Comment: i have #define IO_SEG_IMAX (IO_SEG - 1) sry i will add it

Comment: I guess the other question, then is do you actually have IO_SEG inputs, or can the number of inputs vary?  I don't see any other error in the code you've provided.